# find inside array of objects

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, linq-to-objects

i have a objectA

```
 public class objectA
 {
     public int Id;
     public string Name;
 }
```

i have a list of objectA

```
List<objectA> list;
```

i want to find in the list any objectA with Id = 10;

is there linq syntax for this or do i simply have to write a loop here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.Where(o => o.Id == 10);
```

Remember: you can chain those method calls, or you can use the IEnumerable returned here for things like databinding.

Answer (score 1):

To return all objects with an Id of ten, you'll need:

```
list.Where(o => o.Id = 10)
```